# how to resolve the error when bind mount using docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I use the following docker run command to bring up the container

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -v /opt/docker/logs:/opt/components/logs \
    --mount type=volume,dst=/opt/components/config,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=none,volume-opt=o=bind,volume-opt=device=/opt/docker/config \
--name ich --env-file doc.env --env component=sample1 -d ich
```

I wanted to create a docker-compose file to mount the same and bring up the container... I use the below and it throws an error

```
version: "3"
services:
    ich:
        image: ich
        container_name: ich
        hostname: ich
        env_file:
            - ./doc.env
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        environment:
          component: "sample1"
        volumes:
          - "/opt/docker/logs:/opt/components/logs"
          bind-test:
            driver: local
            driver_opts:
                type: none
                o: bind
                device: /opt/docker/config
                dst: /opt/components/config
```

I get the error

```
ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block collection
  in "./docker-compose.yaml", line 14, column 11
expected <block end>, but found '?'
  in "./docker-compose.yaml", line 19, column 11
```

Please help in resolving this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `docker-compose` has syntax error, after write the yaml, you could go to [yamllint](http://www.yamllint.com/) to verify your syntax.

For your case, `driver_opts` & `driver` definition is for reused across multiple services, it should be defined under the top-level volumes key like next；

```
volumes: 
  bind-test: 
    driver: local
    driver_opts: 
      device: /opt/docker/config
      o: bind
      type: none
```

Detail refers to [official guide](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volume-configuration-reference).

Samples for how you use it:

```
version: "3"
services:
    ich:
        image: ubuntu:18.04
        tty: true
        stdin_open: true
        container_name: ich
        hostname: ich
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        environment:
          component: "sample1"
        volumes:
            - bind-test:/etc

volumes:
  bind-test:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
        type: none
        o: bind
        device: /opt/docker/config
```

**Let me explain this:** suppose I put `docker-compose.yaml` in foler `20210608`, and use `docker-compose up -d` to start the containers:

- `- bind-test:/etc` will map `/etc` in container to host file system with volume, the location should be `/var/lib/docker/volumes/20210608_bind-test/_data`, you can in this folder see all contents of `/etc` of container.
- Also, as you specify `driver_opts`, the contents could also be seen in `/opt/docker/config` which mount to `/var/lib/docker/volumes/20210608_bind-test/_data`
- Additional, you could use next to inspect volume:

```
$ docker volume ls | grep bind-test
local     20210608_bind-test
$ docker volume inspect 20210608_bind-test
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2021-06-08T09:38:21+08:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.project": "20210608",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.25.4",
            "com.docker.compose.volume": "bind-test"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/20210608_bind-test/_data",
        "Name": "20210608_bind-test",
        "Options": {
            "device": "/opt/docker/config",
            "o": "bind",
            "type": "none"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

- In host folder I can see `/etc` contents of container:

```
/opt/docker/config$ ls
adduser.conf            debconf.conf    fstab      hosts        ld.so.conf     lsb-release    opt         profile.d  rc5.d        security  subuid
alternatives            debian_version  gai.conf   init.d       ld.so.conf.d   machine-id     os-release  rc0.d      rc6.d        selinux   sysctl.conf
apt                     default         group      issue        legal          mke2fs.conf    pam.conf    rc1.d      rcS.d        shadow    sysctl.d
bash.bashrc             deluser.conf    gshadow    issue.net    libaudit.conf  mtab           pam.d       rc2.d      resolv.conf  shells    systemd
bindresvport.blacklist  dpkg            host.conf  kernel       login.defs     networks       passwd      rc3.d      rmt          skel      terminfo
cron.daily              environment     hostname   ld.so.cache  logrotate.d    nsswitch.conf  profile     rc4.d      securetty    subgid    update-motd.d
```

Also, if your environment is not clean, you may use next: `docker-compose down -v`, or directly delete some volume to clean use next: `docker volume rm 20210608_bind-test` before do above experiment.

Comment: Tired using the same but the mounting doesn't work as it works when using docker run command as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @JCDani Update for your scenario, you should define target folder in service `ich`, don't define it in `driver_opts`.

Comment: the containers comes up successfully but the mounting fails... I am unable to view the files of the container in host. Currently the host empty folder is overwriting the container files

Comment: no that is not what I need .... if you see the docker run command - it shows the files in the container into the host....which allows the user to modify the configuration , whereas the compose file one doesnt do the same... I am trying to recreate the docker run with the docker-compose file as well

Comment: to achieve host to container file visibility , I believe just standard volume syntax would do the trick and no need for the bind-mount... Please could you help a bit here

Comment: Could you try exact same with my upgrade one in answer? In my local, on host's `/opt/docker/config` I will see all `/etc` in container, this is what you needed?

Comment: Could you try exact same with my upgrade one in answer? - i tried the same what is mentioned exactly by you  and it didnt work for me .This is what you needed? yes

Comment: on running docker volume inspect bind-test, it gives me the error  docker volume inspect bind-test
[]
Error: No such volume: bind-test

Comment: 1. It's not bind-test, you should use `docker volume ls` to find it. 2. I'm not sure what happened on your side, as you said you even can't reproduce the same example I afforded. 3. I updated more detail to answer, would you double confirm all items? Environment clean? Or even use another clean environment?

Comment: Super, it worked ... just like the way I wanted it....thanks in tons